# JavaFX File Association Icon Doesn't Show On LInux

Tags: java, linux, javafx, deb

I'm using the Oracle “Self-Contained Application Packaging” tool to make installable bundles for a JavaFX 8 desktop application.  I include a file association with an icon.  This works on Mac and Windows but on Linux the icon doesn't show for the files created with the file association.

I run the packaging tool from a simple Ant script.  The rest of the build is Gradle so I call Ant from Gradle.  Here is the relevant section of the Ant script:

```
<project name="VocabHunter Packaging" basedir=""
         xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    ...
    <target name="jfxbundle" description="Build the application bundle">

        <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
                 uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
                 classpath="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>

        <fx:deploy outdir="${basedir}/build"
                   nativeBundles="${packageType}">
            ...

            <fx:info title="VocabHunter">
                <fx:association description="VocabHunter session"
                                extension="wordy"
                                mimetype="application/x-vnd.VocabHunterSession"
                                icon="${sessionIcon}"/>
            </fx:info>

            ...
        </fx:deploy>
    </target>
</project>
```

The `${sessionIcon}` variable is assigned the value `icons/Doc1024.png` by the Gradle build.

You can see the full script in context [here](https://github.com/VocabHunter/VocabHunter/blob/1.0.16/package/bundle-ant.xml).

If I add `verbose="true"` to the `<fx:deploy>` element and then run Gradle with the `-info` flag I can see that it picks up the application icon but not the file association icon:

```
 Using custom package resource [menu icon]  (loaded from file /VocabHunter/package/icons/App1024.png)
Using default package resource [Menu shortcut descriptor]  (add package/linux/VocabHunter.desktop to the class path to customize)
Using default package resource [DEB control file]  (add package/linux/control to the class path to customize)
Using default package resource [DEB preinstall script]  (add package/linux/preinst to the class path to customize)
Using default package resource [DEB prerm script]  (add package/linux/prerm to the class path to customize)
Using default package resource [DEB postinstall script]  (add package/linux/postinst to the class path to customize)
Using default package resource [DEB postrm script]  (add package/linux/postrm to the class path to customize)
Using default package resource [DEB copyright file]  (add package/linux/copyright to the class path to customize)
```

Does anyone know how to get the file association icon to work for Linux?

On Linux the file type I'm generating is `.deb`.  I'm testing this using JDK 1.8.0_91 on Ubuntu 16.04.